# Jmeter - declare array variable in one JSR223 Sampler in order to access it in another JSR223 Sampler

Tags: groovy, jmeter

So I have 2 JSR223 samplers in Jmeter Thread Group.
In the first one, I declare an empty array list

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

myList = new ArrayList();
```

In the second JSR223 Sampler, that is inside ForEach Controller, I am trying to access `myList` variable in order to add some value

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

myList.add(vars.get('trace_id'));
```

I keep getting the message

```
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myList for class: Script468
```

I was reading [this](https://www.vinsguru.com/jmeter-understanding-the-scope-of-variables-sharing-among-threads-and-thread-groups/) (not official Jmeter docs though) and it says that **By default, creating any new variables are local to a thread. It can not be accessed by other threads in the same thread group / other thread groups in the Test plan.** so I was thinking I do everything right.

Is it possible to access the variable declared in one groovy sampler (JSR223) in another JSR223 sampler or I am trying to achieve not feasible scenario here?

Comment: any feedback on answer ? if ok you should accept it and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to do that, in first JSR223 Sampler add this:

> vars.putObject("myList", myList);

In second one:

> def myList = vars.getObject("myList");

See javadocs:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html

Comment: The best answer possible. Thank you very much