# why I can save a groovy closure to JMeter's exposed props Hashtable but not a groovy function?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

#### Question

Anyone know why I can save a groovy closure to JMeter's exposed [props](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) Hashtable but not a groovy function?

#### Minimal example

In a test plan, in a thread group, in a JSR223 sampler with script language Groovy 3.0.3, I have the following minimal failing example (fails both when pasted into the "script" box in the Jmeter GUI or referenced from the file name "test.groovy"):

```
def bern = { p -> Math.random() < p }

props.put("bern", bern)
closure = props.get("bern")

log.warn("props closure call: " + closure(1.0))

def bernoulli (double p) {
    Math.random() < p
}

props.put("bernoulli", bernoulli)
funct = props.get(bernoulli)

log.warn("props function call: " + funct(1.0))
```

Here's my expected output (in the JMeter log viewer)

```
props closure call: true
props function call: true
```

Here's the log output I'm getting

```
props closure call: true
...text
Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptExecution: 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property bernoulli for class:
 Script<jmeter generated groovy script number> ...
```

#### Related

- [Jmeter : How to initialize map once and share it for all threads in a thread group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667316/jmeter-how-to-initialize-map-once-and-share-it-for-all-threads-in-a-thread-gro)
- [Jmeter - declare array variable in one JSR223 Sampler in order to access it in another JSR223 Sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637720/jmeter-declare-array-variable-in-one-jsr223-sampler-in-order-to-access-it-in-a)
- https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-turn-methods-into.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store a function into `props` with the following syntax:

```
// def props = [:]
def bernoulli (double p) {
    Math.random() < p
}

props.put("bernoulli", this.&bernoulli)

funct = props.get("bernoulli")
println funct(1.0)
```

The expression `this.&bernoulli` just converts the `bernoulli` function to a closure using the [method pointer operator](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#method-pointer-operator) `.&`.

Comment: BTW you can remove/comment `def props = [:]` because `props` are already built in in JMeter script

Comment: I'm happy to convert a function to a closure, and this answer also exposes some of the subtleties of groovy's bindings, e.g., the generated script class as `this`, creating a method pointer on the `bernoulli` function.